# How to hide webpart in sharepoint only for specific user or case

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, web-parts, sharepoint-api

I have PublishingLayoutPage and depends on query params i should hide few webparts.

But i dont now how to do this. Because if i understand problem correctly
SPLimitedWebPartManager will hide webpart for all users!

```
            using (SPLimitedWebPartManager mgr = file.GetLimitedWebPartManager(PersonalizationScope.Shared))
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                SPLimitedWebPartCollection webparts = mgr.WebParts;
                                foreach (System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPart wp in webparts)
                                {
                                    if (wp is MyWebpart && !isShowWebpart)
                                    {
wp.Hidden=true;
                                        mgr.SaveChanges(wp );
                                    }
                                }
```

How to hide webpart and doesnot allow to render content only for specific case on page?

Comment: Can you clarify your needs/access?  Is your logic user/role based or is there business logic as well?  Were are you looking at implementing the logic/code?  Do you plan on using Client Object Model or a custom webpart with codebehind for managing other webparts?

Comment: if i have url param like "?view=short" some webparts should be hidden.

Comment: Do you have the abiilty to inclue your own custom server code on the page/layout/masterpage?

Comment: Yes. I have custom PublishingLayoutPage. and there i can get all webparts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you could place this in your Load/PreRender/wherever is appropriate:

```
    List<string> webPartTitlesToHide = new List<string>();
    webPartTitlesToHide.Add("Long Title");
    webPartTitlesToHide.Add("Long Content");
    webPartTitlesToHide.Add("Long Footer");


    if (Request["view"] == "short")
    {
        WebPartManager wpm = WebPartManager.GetCurrentWebPartManager(this);
        foreach (WebPart wp in wpm.WebParts)
        {
            if (webPartTitlesToHide.Contains(wp.Title))
            { 
                wpm.CloseWebPart(wp);
            }
        }
    }
```

Obviously, you probably have a better way of selecting which webparts to hide, but this is just an example.

Comment: In this case nothing happens. Webparts still there.

Comment: When you debug, wp.Visible = false is being executed and it's still showing"

Comment: That's... disturbing. I just tested it on a random page of mine (simply grabbing the first webpart), and it worked as expected.  What event in the life cycle are you hooking into to set the display?  Is it possible something is overriding your visible and forcing it to true?

Comment: I've updated the solution to use CloseWebPart... can you give that a spin and see how if it is more authoritative?

Comment: But when i am closing webpart it becomes closed for all users? Or i am wrong?

Comment: Closing the webpart only affects the current GET and subsquent POSTS (as it is maintained). During the next GET request, the WebPart should be restored/visible.  This should have no effect on parallel users. A quick test for you would be to make the request with `?view=short`, then simply remove `?view=short` to ensure the webpart shows back up.